# failed to parse source map. file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory

Tags: reactjs, npm

I have this issue suddenly and I tried to implement the below code in the package.json file but it still didn't work

```
"scripts": {
"start": "GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=true react-scripts start",
```

Comment: Could you show your whole `package.json` and your file structure? I assume this was made using CRA (create-react-app)